# Linux - Wifi Failing Via Command Line CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED

Tags: linux, debian

I have got a toshiba satellite laptop which I have installed debian linux on.
The network will not connect.
This Is What I Did:

```
wpa_passphrase NetworkName >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And then entered pass.
but when I do

```
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I get the following

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

Then if i try to ping google.com it just fails.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is `wlan0` up? Debian with classic `ifupdown` will automatically call `wpa_supplicant` if you used `wpa-conf` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and no doubt systemd will have a different method, but also call it automatically. Also, my instance uses `-D nl80211,wext`.